# Building RSS feed using XML data from Sakai generated from REST

Tags: javascript, html, rest, rss, sakai

I am trying to build an RSS feed for announcements that are located a Sakai site using data that is only accessible while logged into the site. Is there any way to make that data accessible?  Currently, only that is preventing this code from functioning:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    (function() {
                        var params = {rssmikle_url: "https://sakai.uri.edu/direct/announcement/site/d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530/rss.xml",rssmikle_frame_width: "720",rssmikle_frame_height: "350",frame_height_by_article: "0",rssmikle_target: "_blank",rssmikle_font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif",rssmikle_font_size: "12",rssmikle_border: "off",responsive: "off",rssmikle_css_url: "",text_align: "left",text_align2: "left",corner: "off",scrollbar: "on",autoscroll: "off",scrolldirection: "up",scrollstep: "3",mcspeed: "20",sort: "Off",rssmikle_title: "on",rssmikle_title_sentence: "",rssmikle_title_link: "",rssmikle_title_bgcolor: "#393C47",rssmikle_title_color: "#FFFFFF",rssmikle_title_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_bgcolor: "#C0C0C0",rssmikle_item_bgimage: "",rssmikle_item_title_length: "55",rssmikle_item_title_color: "#0066FF",rssmikle_item_border_bottom: "on",rssmikle_item_description: "on",item_link: "off",rssmikle_item_description_length: "150",rssmikle_item_description_color: "#000000",rssmikle_item_date: "gl1",rssmikle_timezone: "Etc/GMT",datetime_format: "%b %e, %Y %l:%M %p",item_description_style: "text+tn",item_thumbnail: "full",item_thumbnail_selection: "auto",article_num: "15",rssmikle_item_podcast: "off",keyword_inc: "",keyword_exc: ""};feedwind_show_widget_iframe(params);})();</script>
                    <div style="margin:auto; font-size:10px; text-align:center; width:300px;"><a href="http://feed.mikle.com/" target="_blank" style="color:#CCCCCC;">RSS Feed Widget</a>
                    <!--Please display the above link in your web page according to Terms of Service.--></div>
```

The XML file, when the user has appropriate permission, looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<announcement_collection entityPrefix="announcement">
<announcement type="bean" size="13">
  <announcementId>3a6439ff-ba41-4a8d-aed5-06a3a534b41f</announcementId>
  <attachments type="collection" size="0">
  </attachments>
  <body>&lt;p&gt;
    &lt;span style="font-size:12px;"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"&gt;Team,&lt;br/&gt;
    &lt;br/&gt;
    Apple has discontinued the 27" Thunderbolt Display. &amp;nbsp;As a result, they are no longer selling LCD or LED monitors under the Apple brand.&lt;br/&gt;
    &lt;br/&gt;
    To compensate this, we are offering two standard alternative options for customers (usually faculty) who were previously interested in the Apple one.&lt;br/&gt;
    &lt;br/&gt;
    Option 1:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p class="a-size-large a-spacing-none" style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; font-weight: 400; color: rgb(17, 17, 17); margin-bottom: 0px !important; font-size: 21px !important; line-height: 1.3 !important;"&gt;
    &lt;span style="font-size:12px;"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"&gt;&lt;span class="a-size-large" id="productTitle" style="box-sizing: border-box; text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; line-height: 1.3 !important;"&gt;&lt;strong&gt;HP Pavilion 27xw 27-in IPS LED Backlit Monitor&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p class="a-size-large a-spacing-none" style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; font-weight: 400; color: rgb(17, 17, 17); margin-bottom: 0px !important; font-size: 21px !important; line-height: 1.3 !important;"&gt;
    &lt;span style="font-size:12px;"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"&gt;&lt;span class="a-size-large" style="box-sizing: border-box; text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; line-height: 1.3 !important;"&gt;Resolution is 1920 x 1080&lt;br/&gt;
    Warranty: 1 Year&lt;br/&gt;
    Price for customers is: &lt;strong&gt;$299.99&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
    &lt;br/&gt;
    Option 2:&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
    &amp;nbsp;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p class="a-size-large a-spacing-none" style="box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-left: 0px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; font-weight: 400; color: rgb(17, 17, 17); margin-bottom: 0px !important; font-size: 21px !important; line-height: 1.3 !important;"&gt;
    &lt;span style="font-size:12px;"&gt;&lt;span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;"&gt;&lt;span class="a-size-large" id="productTitle" style="box-sizing: border-box; text-rendering: optimizeLegibility; line-height: 1.3 !important;"&gt;&lt;strong&gt;Dell Ultra HD 4k Monitor P2715Q 27-Inch Screen LED-Lit Monitor&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
    Resolution is: 3840 x 2860 (4k)&lt;br/&gt;
    Warranty: 3 Years&lt;br/&gt;
    Price for customers is: &lt;strong&gt;$545.99&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
    &lt;br/&gt;
    If a customer is interested in something different, we can absolutely accommodate their needs. &amp;nbsp;Simply search through our distributors for whatever they would like. &amp;nbsp;These two are meant to act as standard "go-to's" which you can offer. &amp;nbsp;Both will be in the products table under Monitors.&lt;br/&gt;
    &lt;br/&gt;
    Although they do have a large price difference between them, the 4k option is still around half the price of the old Apple Thunderbolt Display. &amp;nbsp;&lt;br/&gt;
    &lt;br/&gt;
    It is important to note that all Macs aside from the Retina Pros will need an adapter to connect: either Mini DisplayPort to HDMI or USB-C to HDMI.&lt;br/&gt;
    &lt;br/&gt;
    Any questions about these two options can be brought up to Kira or Jackie.&lt;br/&gt;
    &lt;br/&gt;
    Thank you for all that you do,&lt;br/&gt;
    &lt;br/&gt;
    -Jack&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</body>
  <createdByDisplayName>Jack Sparrow</createdByDisplayName>
  <createdOn type="date" date="2016-08-09T15:48:34-04:00">1470772114473</createdOn>
  <id>d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530:main:3a6439ff-ba41-4a8d-aed5-06a3a534b41f</id>
  <siteId>d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530</siteId>
  <siteTitle>RAM Computers</siteTitle>
  <title>Alternatives to Apple Thunderbolt</title>
  <entityReference>/announcement/d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530:main:3a6439ff-ba41-4a8d-aed5-06a3a534b41f</entityReference>
  <entityURL>https://sakai.uri.edu/direct/announcement/d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530:main:3a6439ff-ba41-4a8d-aed5-06a3a534b41f</entityURL>
  <entityId>d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530:main:3a6439ff-ba41-4a8d-aed5-06a3a534b41f</entityId>
  <entityTitle>Alternatives to Apple Thunderbolt</entityTitle>
</announcement>
<announcement type="bean" size="13">
  <announcementId>f3e21f61-c88a-4e8a-819a-494aff0301c1</announcementId>
  <attachments type="collection" size="0">
  </attachments>
  <body>Hey everyone,&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;
If you don't know, we have Monday, August 8th off for Victory day! So don't come in and make sure customers know we will not be open.&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;
Sincerely,&lt;br/&gt;
Your Student Leaders&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;</body>
  <createdByDisplayName>Elizabeth Swan</createdByDisplayName>
  <createdOn type="date" date="2016-08-05T11:10:08-04:00">1470409808216</createdOn>
  <id>d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530:main:f3e21f61-c88a-4e8a-819a-494aff0301c1</id>
  <siteId>d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530</siteId>
  <siteTitle>RAM Computers</siteTitle>
  <title>Monday, August 8th</title>
  <entityReference>/announcement/d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530:main:f3e21f61-c88a-4e8a-819a-494aff0301c1</entityReference>
  <entityURL>https://sakai.uri.edu/direct/announcement/d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530:main:f3e21f61-c88a-4e8a-819a-494aff0301c1</entityURL>
  <entityId>d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530:main:f3e21f61-c88a-4e8a-819a-494aff0301c1</entityId>
  <entityTitle>Monday, August 8th</entityTitle>
</announcement>
<announcement type="bean" size="13">
  <announcementId>b339bfc7-4425-4533-a49f-630ebe8733c0</announcementId>
  <attachments type="collection" size="0">
  </attachments>
  <body>Hi everyone,&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;
Please read this email it is VERY IMPORTANT!&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;
If you don't already know, there is an Ordered Folder that is kept by Kira's desk. If you can't find it, let me know. Whenever we get an order in, and we don't have the laptop in stock, the order (along with all of the agreements, if applicable) should be paper clipped and placed in this folder. Once the laptop has arrived, whoever is checking it in, it is your responsibility to:&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;
1. Check the PO reference (in this box it will list whether the laptop is for a specific CO, RR, or stock)&lt;br/&gt;
2. Check the Ordered Folder for the corresponding CO or RR papers&lt;br/&gt;
3. Place the laptop with the Order papers and BEGIN BUILD!&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;
We have had a few orders that have been delayed due to people not following this process. I understand that not everyone was aware that this folder existed, but now everyone will be held accountable.&amp;nbsp;&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;em&gt;&lt;strong&gt;*We currently have ~15 orders waiting for laptops to come in that are in this folder*&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/em&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;
&lt;br/&gt;
Thank you,&lt;br/&gt;
Alex Swan</body>
  <createdByDisplayName>Elizabeth Swan</createdByDisplayName>
  <createdOn type="date" date="2016-08-03T10:55:12-04:00">1470236112109</createdOn>
  <id>d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530:main:b339bfc7-4425-4533-a49f-630ebe8733c0</id>
  <siteId>d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530</siteId>
  <siteTitle>RAM Computers</siteTitle>
  <title>ORDER FOLDER</title>
  <entityReference>/announcement/d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530:main:b339bfc7-4425-4533-a49f-630ebe8733c0</entityReference>
  <entityURL>https://sakai.uri.edu/direct/announcement/d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530:main:b339bfc7-4425-4533-a49f-630ebe8733c0</entityURL>
  <entityId>d3b8756d-0f80-4ebf-89d1-eda270785530:main:b339bfc7-4425-4533-a49f-630ebe8733c0</entityId>
  <entityTitle>ORDER FOLDER</entityTitle>
</announcement>
</announcement_collection>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a direct link to the announcements provided by Sakai: 
`https://[sakai site]/access/announcement/rss/[rss feed name].rss`

Replacing the rssmikle_url with this link fixes the issue.

Comment: Don't know if you can see these comments, but would really appreciate your help on this. I'm in a similar situation and I just can't figure out the parts of the url to substitute in the answer for the old one. It would be super helpful if you wouldn't mind posting the full url.